Very simple App will not compile in Xcode with error that it can't find YogaKit
I'm getting this error on a very simple app:
/Users/mitchgreer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KairosTimer2-gxpqydcwjdfhzybaymdaiirfhuzg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/KairosTimer2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/KairosTimer2.build/DerivedSources/KairosTimer2_vers.c module map file 
'/Users/mitchgreer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KairosTimer2-gxpqydcwjdfhzybaymdaiirfhuzg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found 


and when I try and install on my phone for testing,it hangs at:
➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods'
        ➜ Expl

I'v been working on this for a full day, reinstalling modules and pods, clearing cache, reinstalling npm.
I have found YogaKit at /Users/mitchgreer/Documents/GitHub/KairosTimer2/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/YogaKit.modulemap
But I still get the error.
The app was tested and working 8 months ago, and uploaded to the app store, I need to do this again. Any help would be really appreciated.
I'v been working on this for a full day, reinstalling modules and pods, clearing cache, reinstalling npm.The app was tested and working 8 months ago, and uploaded to the app store, I need to do this again. Any help would be really appreciated.

Try to delete the podfile.lock and reinstall via  npx pod-install from project root and not the ios folder

Just tried it. Still the same problem

Are you using an apple silicon Mac ?

I'm using an M2 Pro

Amend you Podfile like described here https://github.com/aiba/react-native-m1/blob/main/README.md#now-edit-myappiospodfile
